How to get the HTML/Junit/Allure reports in Specific mentioned folder
Whenever I try to generate the report using cmd line --html="//reports.html", it's always generating in HTML report PageAction Folder.
I want that to be specifically come under Reports Folder. I changed path like --html="Reports//reports.html" but it's not working. What's the solution?
Screenshots for reference
